# Rust overflowing shift left

Tags: rust, bit-manipulation, logical-operators, bit-shift

I'm trying to combine 4 bytes into a u32, and the compiler telling me that the shift has overflown.
This is my code:

```rust
pub fn get_instruction(file: &[u8], counter: usize) {
    let ins = u32::from(file[counter] << 24)
        | u32::from(file[counter + 1] << 16)
        | u32::from(file[counter + 2] << 8)
        | u32::from(file[counter + 3]);
    println!("{:x}", ins);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got your operator priority and cast wrong:

```rust
pub fn get_instruction(file: &[u8], counter: usize) {
    let ins = u32::from(file[counter]) << 24
        | u32::from(file[counter + 1]) << 16
        | u32::from(file[counter + 2]) << 8
        | u32::from(file[counter + 3]);
    println!("{:x}", ins);
}
```

You were casting *after* trying to shift a `u8` 24 bits, which was your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to twiddle the bits yourself – you can use the function [`u32::from_be_bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.u32.html#method.from_be_bytes) instead:

```
pub fn get_instruction(file: &[u8], counter: usize) {
    let ins_bytes = <[u8; 4]>::try_from(&file[counter..counter + 4]).unwrap();
    let ins = u32::from_be_bytes(ins_bytes);
    println!("{:x}", ins);
}
```

Comment: This takes an array, while his method takes a slice and initial position though.

Comment: @mcarton Which is why the code first converts the slice to an array. If we are concerned about the performance impact, we could also `transmute()` the slice to an array.